# pstore.bin keeps changing its file status to "read-only"

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

I am using Android Studio and repeatedly getting the error of:

> Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open
>   C:\Users\user.android\avd\Nexus_S_API_23.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin:
>   Permission denied

I have unticked the "Read only" tick box more than a dozen times. Why does it still happen to tick back?

Answer (score -1):

The error is harmless to most users.

See the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072173, which referenced bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73249556